# How to display multiple headers

Tags: html, vue.js

I am trying to display multiple headers all on the same horizontal line. So far, I am able to display two of them, but the third keeps falling down a line. The following is an image of the what it currently looks like:

[current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emyIc.png)

The current code to display the headers:

```
  <header>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="text-align:center;float:left;" >Amazon</h1>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="text-align:center;float:center;">BestBuy</h1>
        <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="text-align:right;float:right;">Target</h1> 
      <hr style="clear:all;"/> 
      </header>
```

Comment: There's not much in this screenshot or HTML to go on. I'd suspect the `display-3` class matters a lot here, but who knows?

Comment: Code in question produces a minimal example

Comment: Note that the `<hr>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: The words: "Best Buy" are not aligned properly in your screenshot as well, maybe consider changing your font size?

Comment: @B.Oss I tried reducing the font size, but Target still shows under the line. When I remove the Target h1 tag then BestBuy is alligned.

Comment: @Bryan you should try to use the [Bootstrap Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Using Float left and defining the width we can easily display the Headers without much complexity of code.

```html
<header>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style=" width:30%; text-align:left; float:left;" >Amazon</h1>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style=" width:40%; text-align:center; float:left;">BestBuy</h1>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="width:30%; text-align:right;float:left;">Target</h1> 
      <hr style="clear:all;"> 
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to get Target onto the same line was to add `display: inline-block;` to the style of each `<h1>`. 
The trouble then became centering BestBuy, which was done by setting it to `position: absolute;` and centering it based on window size with `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`.

Final working code:

```
<header>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="text-align:left; display:inline-block" >Amazon</h1>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="position: absolute; text-align:center; left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%); display:inline-block;">BestBuy</h1>
      <h1 class="text-sm display-3 font-weight-thin " style="text-align:right; float: right; display:inline-block">Target</h1> 
      <hr style="clear:all;"> 
</header>
```